# iPad After drill down in Split View's Master View, Detail View will not load

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, ipad

completely new to coding other than html.
I have an iPad app based on the MultiDetailsView/SplitView sample in Xcode.
I have a master view that drills down and loads new detail views, both at the same time when needed.
But when I do drill down the lower views will not load their new detail views.
If I change the master 'RootViewController' in the Main nib to any of my other navigation views they will load their correct detail views.

I think it could be that my lower views are somehow not connected to the SplitViewController.
I have tried many things but I am just guessing.

Any help with this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to post some sample code to get help. But you can do what you want. You can push and pop views on either side from either side.